# Console application that can find and run certain exe

Tags: c#

I want to make small console application that can find and run certain exe. This works, however it is extremely slow in given situations. Any Idea how can i improve this?

```
string[] drives = Directory.GetLogicalDrives();
string pathToExecutable = String.Empty;

foreach (string drive in drives)
{
    pathToExecutable =
     Directory.EnumerateFiles(drive, "vlc.exe",
     new EnumerationOptions
     {
         IgnoreInaccessible = true,
         RecurseSubdirectories = true
     }
     )
     .FirstOrDefault();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathToExecutable))
    {
        break;
    }

}

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathToExecutable))
{
    // We did not find the executable.
    Console.WriteLine("We did not find the executable!");
}
else
{
    // We found the executable. Now we can start it.
    Console.WriteLine("We found the executable. Now we can start it");

    var proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = pathToExecutable;
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
    proc.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can you to narrow down the directories where the vlc.exe can reside?

Comment: Have you looked into PLinq?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq   something like `Directory.GetLogicalDrives().AsParallel().SelectMany(drive => Directory.EnumerateFiles(drive, "vlc.exe", new EnumerationOptions())).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @PeterCsala, ofcourse I can narrow down the directories but that is not the point. The point is to search the whole PC.

Comment: @CharlesNRice, No I haven't. I will look into it

Comment: I would vote against parallelizing disk seeks if all drives are on the same HDD. Sequential access might be better than random accesses.

Comment: Have you tried using Windows Search APIs, it might be faster for directories which are already indexed.

Comment: @CodeNameJack, no I haven't. I will look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's get the code review out of the way.  Your style, casing, and object naming are decent.  I take some small issue with some indentation, but that's a matter of style.

However, your Comments are utterly useless.

```
// We did not find the executable.
Console.WriteLine("We did not find the executable!");
```

Clean code can tell us **what** you are doing so a comment that does the same is repetitive.  Comments should be for **why** you are doing something.  Even here, the why is implicitly known from the code.

You may consider using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of `String.IsNullOrEmpty`.

On to what you really are looking for ...

**How can performance be improved?**

First of all, let's acknowledge that you are performing a crawl over a logical drive that either ends when you find what you or looking for, or else the entire drive has been crawled over.  Do not expect performance to be great.

As mentioned in the comments, parallelizing the drive searches can maybe speed things up, as long as the logical drives exist on different physical drives.  There is a way to check for this, but I am not going into that.

One alternative for better performance the 2nd time around would be to persist the path the first time you find it.  For completeness, you would need to save this **per user per host**.  Maybe on your home PC, you would think the drives are common for everyone in the home, but for a work computer, the attached network shares mapped as logical drives can vary **per user per host**.  The notion of a persisted appsetting is that you would first check the last known path, and if it is found, you have no need to crawl over anything.

Another alternative is to assign the path once it is found to the PATH Environment variable.  Note: PATH itself is set automatically **per user per host**.  You would then search on each directory in PATH but do not recurse subdirectories.

A similar alternative would be to create a new Environment variable, e.g. PathToVlcExe.  One the path has been found with a sluggish crawl and this setting has been saved, the next execution you would first check to see if that path is
**still valid**, in which case you skip the crawl.

Each alternative is dependent upon performing a very sluggish crawl the first time.  Unless you think that vlc.exe should be somewhere along a known Environment PATH, in which case you should limit the search to Environment PATH, again without recursing subdirectories.

Yet another alternative would be to **somehow** narrow down the path to vlc.exe.  If you knew it was going to be either in "?:\Program Files (x86)?????" or "?:\Program Files?????", then you could greatly speed up the search.  As we know, an executable does not have to be installed into any of the Program Files folders, but the downside is what you are now experiencing: horrically slow search times as you crawl over a logical drive.